# how do you check different api calls until it is succesful in python

Tags: python, api

I have a server list:

```
hosts=['server1','server2','server3','server4']
```

there are server 4 monitoring tools accessed by api calls. these monitoring env urls basically the same except for each env has unique id which is part of the url. These servers can be on any of the 4 monitoring tools. I need to find out which url these servers belong to.

for example, these are the monitoring tools urls:

```
production_env="https://example.com/e/envid123"
dev_env="https://example.com/e/envid678"
test_env="https://example.com/e/envid567"
uat_env="https://example.com/e/envid1000"
```

given the server name, I need to find out which env they belong to.

given a server name, for example "server1",

api url would become `https://example.com/e/envid123&serverName="server1"`, this url will give whether server1 exists in production_env or not. I need to check each env url until I find the given server.

I am trying something like this:

```
envId=['envid123','envid678','envid567','envid1000']

for server in hosts:
   for id in envId:
    url="https://example.com/e/"+id+&serverName=server
    resp=request.get(url)
```

Any ideas how could do this the best way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you trying to solve an error in your current code? If so, what is the error. Or are you asking something else?

Comment: Side note: don't build a URL query with string concatenation. Instead, use [`urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) to mitigate injection attacks. Also it is really handy to build the query from a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around `&serverName=` to concatenate them. But it's simpler to use a formatting method, such as f-strings.

To find the desired URL, use `resp.json` to get the decoded JSON, and check the value of the appropriate dictionary element.

```
found = False
for server in hosts:
    for id in envId:
        url = f"https://example.com/e/{id}&serverName={server}"
        resp = request.get(url)
        if resp.json['totalCount'] > 0:
            found = True
            print(f"Success at host = {server} id = {id}")
            break
    if found:
        break
else:
    print("No server found")
```

Comment: I dont know any problems forming the url. I need to form the url until I find the server, that's the question.

Comment: The code you posted has syntax errors, it won't work, so I thought that was the problem.

Comment: What problem do you have with stopping when you find the server? Just check the value of `resp.text`, and break out of the loops when done.

Comment: Does the request fail when the URL is wrong? Use `try/except` to detect this and break out when it succeeds.

Comment: the request will not fail. Request will be empty.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: if resp.txt, I get this error "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: `request.get()` doesn't return a `dict`. See https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content

Comment: the req out is something like this: {'totalCount': 1, 'pageSize': 50, 'entities': [{'entityId': '1230', 'displayName': 'server1'}]}

Comment: That's the result of parsing JSON, you'd get that from `resp.json`. I'm assuing you're using the standard Python `requests` module.

Comment: empty resp will look like this "{'totalCount': 0, 'pageSize': 50, 'entities': []}

Comment: So it's really the value of `totalCount` that matters?

Comment: Why isn't any of this information in the question? How could anyone possibly know that it's returning JSON even when empty.

Comment: @user1471980 You should edit your question to include the relevant information to explain what problem you are having. As your question stands, there isn't enough detail for us to understand what you are actually asking about.

Comment: @user1471980 The logic is the same no matter how you determine whether the response is empty.

Comment: @Barmar, I accepted your answer. Thank you. Quick question, I have various scnerios where resp may be different. I use if resp.txt, but I keep getting AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: I still don't understand that, unless `request` is something other than `requests.request`.